# Chat events (suggestions)

Tags: discussion

I was discussing in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5144102#5144102) about starting up a regular chat event, in order to draw more traffic to the site.
I am posting this just to see how everyone else feels about it, and whether they have any suggestions for what sort of events to hold.
Two ideas that were brought up:

`1: Weekly halaqa`

`2: regular Arabic classes`

Comment: In order to participate chat user need at least 20 rep in this site , so anon user's can't participate

Comment: +1 For both... Arabic classes umm....... ! Great!

Comment: @AboobackerMk: you need 20 rep (on *any* SE site, I believe, not just this one) to participate in the chat (i.e., to say anything), but the chat will still be *visible* to everybody, even anonymous users.

Comment: @goldPseudo how will the doubts be cleared then?

Comment: I would like to know how the halaqa is organized. Because, having halaqa would mean teaching based on one perspective i.e. Sunni or Shia. Or do we have different chat rooms for that? Or Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Ershad we're just sorta tossing around ideas for regular events right now. we as a community can decide how any halaqa is organized once (read: if) there's enough interest.

Comment: I don't think chat traffic is considered part of the traffic to the site at all. What counts in the traffic to site number is traffic to the main site only. A large portion of the traffic to the site will (hopefully) be from search engines eventually (IIRC, SE says it should get up to something like 90 percent of all traffic). I am not sure if chat events will have much effect on that. What can help us increase the traffic is having links to the main site and/or posts on the main site from other popular sites so it gets a better pagerank.

Comment: @Kaveh , yup but good events will attract more users ,to the sitee, It will also help to increase  egular users

Comment: I've posted an answer which I think is a decent middle-ground: pick a good topic to chat, and potentially one that can be a good source of questions.

Answer (score 3):

### Weekly Reflections

Once a week, we reflect on an Ayah, or certain Ayahs and we talk about it's meaning and how to implement it in our lives.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to approach this from a different perspective.

The current perspective is that "chat is good and chat events will draw people to the site." I agree with that.

I would like people to consider topics that **they think may be a good source of juicy questions for the site.** That is, topics that are deep and wide, and will cause a flurry of research, self-study, and possibly questions on the site.

For example, we can discuss *the lives of past prophets,* which is well-known and well-documented in hadith. It's also a good source of (mostly academic) questions.

So I recommend thinking along those lines -- chat for the sake of traffic, and also chat that may spurn good questions.

Answer (score 2):

## Real-Time Meta Discussion

Each week, we decide what's going on with the site, what we can improve, and what we can fix.

Comment: chat is not a good place for meta-discussions (which should be easily accessible to everyone over after a long period of time), it is mainly for personal discussions between users.

Comment: @Kaveh We can summarize each week in Meta....

Comment: then it can be fine I guess.

Answer (score 2):

### Ramadan Preparations

Every week for two weeks before Ramadan, we prepare our self's for Ramadan.

Answer (score 1):

### Monthly Report

Once a Month we give a report of site activity and news that happened for that month.

Answer (score 1):

**Online Jumu'ah (Hudba).**

Let's find some scholar who will narrate , and write once per week one lecture holding one theme.

Answer (score 0):

## ISLAMIC QUIZ

I would like to suggest Islamic quiz in the weekend .

Answer (score 0):

## Story time

historic Islamic stories once in week

Comment: Oh boy.. we got enough of these

Comment: Because they're interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction to Islam.SE for new users

A chat event once a week or two weeks that introduces to new users Islam.SE, it's rules, and how it works.  Also a chance to attempt to remove the forum mentality from people.

Answer (score 0):

### Monthly community meeting

As I, and a number of other have observed, this site lacks good organization, and activity in regards to the building of this site.  So what I would like to propose, is we have a community meeting, in which we try to get a large amount (if not all) and we discuss the following:

- Issues this site is facing and how we can try to resolve them
- Discuss what is going on in the site:

  - [Meta discussion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/249/9)

    - Recent posts etc...
- Discuss in regards to building this site

The above was just what I could think of, I suspect some things can be added to it and so on.  Furthermore I think these meetings should occur once a month, all moderators should be present, and we should choose at least three people who speak in different regards, in other words one of them can talk about the issues the site is facing and then we can discuss how we can try to resolve, and the same for the other two and so on.

Furthermore, I think this event should be categorized as a "main" event for this site.

Comment: All users can *access* the main chatroom to read, even with low rep (and even while suspended); the 20 rep is only necessary to be able to participate.